# Use a structure in an API call

Tags: php, mailchimp

I'm using the Mailchimp API and trying to deliver dynamic content during the campaign creation. The API can be found here: https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/campaigns/create.php

I'm trying to use sections under the content heading to deliver custom content to my newsletter.

I tried the following code:

```
$content = array();
$content['sections'] = array( 'wordpress_post_content'=>'This is new text' );
```

I created my editable section as `mc:edit="wordpress_post_content"`. The API says that it needs to be in a structure. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you posting in JSON?
Convert using json_encode if you are using PHP.